# Run a Perl Script from PHP/Apache

Tags: php, linux, perl, apache, exec

On RED HAT LINUX: Running APACHE

From a PHP script I want to run a Perl script and am trying to do so with the following command:

```
exec("/usr/bin/perl /home/path/to/perlscript/main.pl", $output, $result);
```

This seems to fail because the PERL script needs to be run by another user (USER1).

I have tried without success to use SUDO. I have to run the script as (USER1) instead of user (APACHE) because (USER1) has more privileges than APACHE user.

Any idea how I would do this?

Comment: I would **hope** that you weren't able to get the web server to `sudo` anything!  You'll need to alter the permission of the file so that the web server can access and run it.

Comment: USER1 (or ROOT) has to be the one run the Perl Script since that user has privileges to run certain commands like Kill process. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it's comprehensible as a sentence, but no, it's a **terrible, terrible idea**.  If you let your web server run things as root, you're begging for trouble.  The web server, as a user, can kill off processes that it creates.

Comment: point taken. back to the drawing board.

Comment: What does the Perl script do?

Comment: have a proprietary DB that I have 2 licenses for. If the two licenses are used (most likely due to a hung query) I want to check a status and kill the associated PID's. It hasn't been easy.

Comment: Have you tried using lock files (along with `flock`)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7013/discussion-between-mmundiff-and-jack-maney)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without fully knowing what your perl script is doing, maybe consider running a cronjob that runs the perl script. This way it's isolated from Apache altogether and still can operate as root without compromising your server.

Comment: Or write a daemon that monitors your database server by what ever means it allows for pinging it or monitoring it through SNMP.